# Minimize $\frac{(x^2+1)(y^2+1)(z^2+1)}{ (x+y+z)^2}$, $x,y,z>0$

Tags: calculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

Minimize $\;\;\displaystyle \frac{(x^2+1)(y^2+1)(z^2+1)}{ (x+y+z)^2}$, if $x,y,z>0$. 
By setting gradient to zero I found $x=y=z=\frac{1}{\displaystyle\sqrt{2}}$, which could minimize the function.

> Question from Jalil Hajimir

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Do you not think that you found the correct answer? Maybe you should show us what the gradient of this function is.

Comment: WIf first derivative is zero it does not min the point is ma or min.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=grad+of+%28x%5E2%2B1%29%28y%5E2%2B1%29%28z%5E2%2B1%29%2F%28+x%2By%2Bz%29%5E2

Comment: so you need $z=1/(x+y)$, $x=1/(y+z)$ and $y=1/(x+z)$ and you found $x=y=z=1/\sqrt{2}$. One way to check if it is a minimum is to find the eigenvalues of the Hessian at the point in question.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=hessian+of+%28%28x%5E2%2B1%29%28y%5E2%2B1%29%28z%5E2%2B1%29%2F%28+x%2By%2Bz%29%5E2%29+

Comment: We have to show the point iis global minimum

Comment: You should state important details like that in your questions.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Hessian+of+%28x%5E2%2B1%29%28y%5E2%2B1%29%28z%5E2%2B1%29%2F%28+x%2By%2Bz%29%5E2+at+x%3D2%5E-.5%2Cy%3D2%5E-.5%2Cz%3D2%5E-.5

Comment: The Hessian doesn't help us here unfortunately. If the determinant was positive then we would know that all the eigenvalues are positive and the sufficient conditions for local minimization would be satisfied.

Comment: @Keon I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: I am trying to some how using convexity, seems I can not. May be the optimization method is not helping let me change my approach. Please do not post your solution in next 30 minutes.

Comment: I have to show (x^2+1)(y^2+1)(z^2+1)>=3/4(x+y+z)^2, I do not think it is hard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=\frac{a}{\sqrt2},$ $y=\frac{b}{\sqrt2}$ and $z=\frac{c}{\sqrt2}.$

Thus, since we can assume that $(a^2-1)(b^2-1)\geq0,$ by C-S we obtain:
$$\frac{(x^2+1)(y^2+1)(z^2+1)}{(x+y+z)^2}=\frac{(a^2+2)(b^2+2)(c^2+2)}{4(a+b+c)^2}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{3(a^2+b^2+1)(1+1+c^2)}{4(a+b+c)^2}\geq\frac{3(a+b+c)^2}{4(a+b+c)^2}=\frac{3}{4}.$$
The equality occurs for $x=y=z=\frac{1}{\sqrt2},$ which says that we got a minimal value.

Comment: Beautiful proof! It took me a while to figure out why we can assume $(a^2-1)(b^2-1)\ge 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You first fix $y, z$ and let $x > 0$ vary. Taking derivative with respect to $x$, dropping all those nonnegative terms such as $y^2+1$ to simplify notation, leads to
$$ \frac{d (OP\ full\ epxr)}{d x} \approx  x - \frac{(x^2+1)}{x+y+z} = \frac{x(y+z) - 1}{x+y+z}, $$
where the $\approx$ means I dropped some positive terms (they do not affect my analysis of the positivity of the derivate).

It is evident that the gradient is negative for small $x$, and once $x > \frac{1}{y+z}$ the gradient becomes positive. Hence the function is minimized at $x = \frac{1}{y+z}$ when $y, z$ are fixed. Similarly, the function is minized at $y = \frac{1}{x+z}$ when $x, z$ are fixed. And the function is minimized at $z = \frac{1}{x+y}$ when $x, y$ are fixed.

Let the global minimizing point be $x_0, y_0, z_0$, given the previous arguments, we must have $x_0= \frac{1}{y_0+z_0}, y_0 = \frac{1}{x_0+z_0}, z_0 = \frac{1}{x_0+y_0} \Rightarrow x_0 = y_0 = z_0 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ (otherwise, we can find a point with smaller value).

Hence the global minimum is unique at $x = y = z = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ if one exists.

For rigorous argument that the a global minimum exists, one can look at a compact set $[\epsilon, N]\times[\epsilon, N]\times [\epsilon, N]$. The function must have a global minimum in the compact set. One can easily argue it does not take minimum at the boundary (contradicts requirements previously stated, or compare function value on the boundary with that of $x = y = z = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$). Hence the minimum MUST be in the interior (with gradients being zero).

Hence $x = y = z = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ is the unique global minimum.

Comment: This is nice, but shows the point is a local minimum.

Comment: Is the first display math line a typo? How can the differentiation operator be equal in sign to an expression of $x,y,z$?

Comment: Made some clarifications regarding the "typo" & global minimum.

Comment: You assumed global min exist.

Comment: Again added details due to your demand.

Comment: How do we know it is minimum?

Comment: If you want you can compute the Hessian at the $x=y=z=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}.$ That should not be hard.

Answer (score 1):

If you want some calculus/analysis argument:

After establishing there must exist a global minimum, let $p$ be the global minimum. Then we must have that
$$f(x) = x^2\left((y^2+1)(z^2+1) - p\right) - 2xp(y+z) + (y^2+1)(z^2+1) - p(y+z)^2\geq 0$$
as a quadratic in $x.$ So the discriminant is non-positive:
$$D =4\left[p^2(y+z)^2 - (y^2+1)^2(z^2+1)^2 - p^2(y+z)^2+(y^2+1)(z^2+1)p(1+(y+z)^2)\right]\leq 0\iff $$
$$p\leq\min\dfrac{(y^2+1)(z^2+1)}{1+(y+z)^2}.$$
But
$$4(y^2+1)(z^2+1) - 3 - 3(y+z)^2 = 4y^2z^2+y^2+z^2-6yz+1 = (y-z)^2+(2yz-1)^2\geq 0.$$ So $p = \dfrac{3}{4}$ by continuity argument and it is achieved by $y = z = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},$ which in return easily tells us that that $x$ is also $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ for the minimum to be attained.

Comment: How did you come up with p=3/4?

Comment: You obtained $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x > 0$. This does not imply the discriminant is non-positive? For example, $x^2+3x+1 \ge 0$ for all $x > 0$, however, its discriminant is positive.

Comment: @RiverLi hm yeah, guess there is more ironing out the details to do.

Comment: For this problem, I think that the discriminant is non-positive. However one needs a little more steps to obtain this result.