# $(a_1^2+k)(a_2^2+k)....(a_n^2+k)\ge m(a_1+a_2+....a_n)^2,a_i>0, i=1,2...n$

Tags: inequality

Find the best value of m for which the following inequality holds?

$(a_1^2+k)(a_2^2+k)....(a_n^2+k)\ge m(a_1+a_2+....a_n)^2,a_i>0,  i=1,2...n$

In my attempt to solve last two questions. This question is raised.
I saw different form of this question where m is given interms of n and k, but I do not remember what it was.
for example k=2,n=3, m=3/4.@Michael_Rozenberg
I came up with a lower bound which is not good.

Comment: This is almost the same as your other post (given similar constraints) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3454095/minimize-fracx21y21z21-xyz2-x-y-z0

Comment: II can say,It is a generalization to my  questions. I am trying to find the best lower bound.

Comment: It seems that the following generalization is true. $(a_1^2+n-1)(a_2^2+n-1)...(a_n^2+n-1)\geq n^{n-2}(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^2.$ I have a proof also for $n=5$ $n=6$.

Comment: I do not know how i can contact you.@Michael_Rozenberg

Comment: I proved it for $n=7$ and $n=8.$ But I still don't see a proof in the general case.

Comment: I remember this my mentor mentioned once that he proved it.

Comment: IF WE EXCHANGE 2 AND K  IS IT STILL VALID?

Comment: Myy mentor told me he proved the generalztion. Yours exchanging 2 with k, so the generalization is valid.

Comment: Yes, of course. The value of m is changed. I think it's better to prove the inequality in my formulation

Comment: I mean this one:$$(a_1^k+n-1)(a_2^k+n-1)\ldots(a_n^k+n-1)\ge n^{n-k}(a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n)^k$$

Comment: See here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1375298p7611092

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101600/discussion-between-keon-and-michael-rozenberg).